# CakePHP 2.x Acl

Tags: cakephp, authentication, authorization, acl

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I implemented Acl. I followed the official tutorial given, populated the `acos` table by `cake's shell scripting`,used `AclExtras` plugin, then populated the `aros_acos` table using "customized" `initDb` function.

Everything is ok now, the tables are populated successfully. So, I thought I don't need the `allow()/deny()` functions, which I used before for `Authorization`. So I deleted these functions from the `beforeFilter()` functions from the corresponding controllers. But, when I deleted them, I cant access any page(fucnction) in my whole project.

To populate the `acos` table I used this command :

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

To populate the `aros_acos` table I customized the `initDB()` and put it in the `Users` controller and run it.

All tables are populated, everything is good, but its not working the `allow()/deny()` functions defined before I implemented ACL.

My question is, if I use `Acl`, if I have all `ARO`s & `ACO`s stored in the `database`, and if I define all `permissions` in the `database`, then why do I need those `allow()/deny()` functions ? And if I need those, then why should I use `Acl` ? My project was fine without the `Acl` implementation, with the `allow()/deny()` functions.

So, what should I do ?

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Finally I got the `ACL` working. I found that its so easy, I just had to know the `shellscrpting`. I always knew that its implemented well in `CakePHP`, I just have to make it working in my project.

First of all, we have to make `PHP` and `CakePHP` `executable` from our `shell/command prompt`. I did it in `Windows(7)`, will try for `Linux` & `MAC` later.

First, if you dont have PHP executable from your command prompt, go to `My Computer->Properties->Environment Variables(forgot exact path, but you will get it easily)`. Then paste this `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13;` in the `Environment Variable`, where `php5.3.13` is version-specific.

After that, paste this in the same place : `cakephp\lib\Cake\Console`. You can copy the `cakephp` folder to your `htdocs/www` permanently, for later use.

Now, run this in your command prompt : `cake bake all`, and follow the instructions. You must have to have a database, configured in your `config.php` file.

By now, you should be ready with the newly created project. Now follow the `CakePHP documentation` for `ACL`.

Remember, which functions/methods you want to be open for all kind of users, allow them explicitly by `allow()`, in `AppController`, or in the specific controller.

Suppose, you want `pages/index`,`users/login`,`users/signUp` - these 3 pages/functions to be open for all. So, `allow()` them in the `AppController` or in `Pages` & `Users` controllers.